# tkinter - How can I standardize Radiobutton list with variable?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, radio-button

I need to create 2x list of `Radiobutton`s. I wrote then 2 blocks, but I was wondering if I cannot create a function to standardize the structure of the `Radiobutton`s lists and just call the function by changing the variables.

Current code (it works perfectly):

```
import os
from tkinter import *

printtype_list=["Externe","Interne 1","Interne 2"]
language_list=["French","English","German","Spanish","Dutch","Russian"]
Language_label="Languages : "
calculation_label="Calculations type : "
i_printtype_list=0
i_language_list=0

def printtype_choose():
    global printtype_click
    printtype=var_printtype.get()
    if printtype=="Externe":
        printtype_click="uc_Kalkulation"
    elif printtype=="Interne 1":
        printtype_click="uc_Kalkulation1"
    else :
        printtype_click="uc_Kalkulation2"
    print(printtype_click)

def language_choose():
    global language_click
    language=var_language.get()
    if language=="French":
        language_click="Uc_1"
    else :
        language_click="Uc_2"
    print(language_click)

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("800x635")

#----- Beginning of the part to standardize

cadreprinttype=Frame(fenetre)
cadreprinttype.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
printtype_txt=Label(cadreprinttype,text="Calculation type : ",)
printtype_txt.pack(side=LEFT)
var_printtype=StringVar()

for y in range(len(printtype_list)):
    Button_printtype=Radiobutton(cadreprinttype, text=printtype_list[i_printtype_list], 
                                 value=printtype_list[i_printtype_list], 
                                 variable=var_printtype, command=printtype_choose)
    Button_printtype.pack(side=LEFT)
    i_printtype_list+=1



cadrelanguage=Frame(fenetre)
cadrelanguage.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
language_txt=Label(cadrelanguage,text="Languages : ")
language_txt.pack(side=LEFT)
var_language=StringVar()

for y in range(len(language_list)):
    Button_language=Radiobutton(cadrelanguage, text=language_list[i_language_list], 
                                value=language_list[i_language_list], 
                                variable=var_language, command=language_choose)
    Button_language.pack(side=LEFT)
    i_language_list+=1

#----------- End of the part to standardize

fenetre.mainloop()
os.system("pause")
```

I tried with this function but without success.

```
def radio_button(cc,xx,yy,vv):
    cadre_1=Frame(fenetre)
    cadre_1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    label_txt=Label(cadre_1,text=cc)
    label_txt.pack(side=LEFT)
    var=StringVar()

    for y in range(len(xx)):
        Button_1=Radiobutton(cadre_1,text=xx[yy], value=xx[yy], variable=var, command=vv)
        Button_1.pack(side=LEFT)
        yy+=1

    return;

radio_button(cc=calculation_label, xx=printtype_list, yy=i_printtype_list,
             vv=printtype_choose())
```

Comment: I suggest using classes in this case, but what exactly was not working in Your code? also as far as I know using globals is not that good so You should avoid it

Comment: When I m executing the second code with the def, the Python shell appears and disappear after 2 seconds, and the  fenetre=Tk() simply not appears. (of course I put it in the first code to replace the blocks of the Radiobuttons list)

Comment: I posted an answer so check it out and if You have questions: ask them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a class to standardize things is a great idea, but I would implement it in a slightly differently manner than @Matiiss did to make it even more data-driven and generic. You can think of this class as a high-level custom widget.

The two dictionaries in the example code, `calculations_map` and `languages_map`, have a multiple uses in the class. Their keys are used as the text displayed next to each button, and the value associated with each is what the `StringVar` will get set to when the it's clicked. Allt he class' `choose()` method does is retrieve the current value of the `StringVar` and assign it to the `self.click` attribute of the instance (and prints it).

```
import os
from tkinter import *

class RadiobuttonGroup:
    def __init__(self, parent, label_text, button_map):
        self.frame = Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text=label_text + ' :')
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.click = None
        self.var = StringVar(value='_nothing_')
        for button_text, button_value in button_map.items():
            radiobutton = Radiobutton(self.frame,
                                      text=button_text,
                                      value=button_value,
                                      variable=self.var,
                                      command=self.choose)
            radiobutton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def choose(self):
        self.click = self.var.get()
        print(self.click)


calculations_label = 'Calculation type'
calculations_map = {'External': 'uc_Calculation',
                    'Internal 1': 'uc_Calculation1',
                    'Internal 2': 'uc_Calculation2'}

languages_label = 'Language'
languages_map = {'French': 'uc_1',
                 'English': 'uc_2' ,
                 'German': 'uc_3',
                 'Spanish': 'uc_4',
                 'Dutch': 'uc_5',
                 'Russian': 'uc_6'}

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x635')

grp1 = RadiobuttonGroup(window, calculations_label, calculations_map)
grp2 = RadiobuttonGroup(window, languages_label, languages_map)

window.mainloop()
os.system('pause')
```

Here's what it looks like running on my system:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's perfect. Now I'm trying to understand it and it's not very easy since I m really struggling with this concept of self and __init__ . But it's normal. 

Just one more question: my code is longer than that and I need to get the value of self.click for others functions which are not in the class RadiobuttonGroup. 

I tried with global self.click and it's not working. Should I create a "class Outer" for these functions and then put the class RadiobuttonGroup in this "class Outer" also ?

Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. While it's possible to nest class definitions, it's generally not a good approach. Code outside the `RadiobuttonGroup` class can access the `click` attribute of its instances (i.e. `grp1.click` and `grp2.click`) as needed. You could also modify the class to accept an additional argument which was the name of a "callback" function and make its `choose()` method call that supplied function whenever one of its own `Radiobutton`s is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Here You go (this is just an example, You can edit it as You need):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Radiobutton, Frame, IntVar


class Selectors:
    def __init__(self, parent, list_of_names, functions_of_each=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.list_of_names = list_of_names
        self.functions_of_each = functions_of_each

        self.frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.main_var = IntVar()

        for index, name in enumerate(self.list_of_names):
            r = Radiobutton(self.frame, text=name, variable=self.main_var, value=index,
                            command=self.return_value)
            r.pack(side='left')

    def return_value(self):
        value = self.main_var.get()
        if self.functions_of_each is None:
            print(self.list_of_names[value])

        elif self.functions_of_each is not None:
            self.functions_of_each[value]()


def count():
    print(2 + 2)


def print_hello():
    print('hello')


def smile():
    print(':)')


def yahoo():
    print('yahoo, lets go')


group1 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5']

group2 = ['2 + 2', 'print hello', 'smile', 'yahoo']
commands2 = [count, print_hello, smile, yahoo]

root = Tk()

select1 = Selectors(root, group1)
select2 = Selectors(root, group2, commands2)

root.mainloop()
```

The main part of this is the class, the rest is just for an example.

A way to generalize Radiobuttons. Quick explanation about the commands list. The list has to be in the same order as the relevant names list otherwise the intended function will not execute. Also remember to not put parenthesis in that list

More about Radiobuttons [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helps me on any case and I can link to the answer below to better understand !